# Dynamically add edit text to a layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to add an edit text view dynamically to a layout from the java class. However from what I have implemented nothing changes on my action. This is what I have:

```
public final void onCreate(final Bundle i){
    int value = 0;

    isEdit = false;

    try
    {
        super.onCreate(i);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.contactedit);
        ContactList.soundIndicator = 0;
        etPhoneNumber = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        this.etPhoneNumber.add((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumberInput));

        this.addNumberBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addNumberEditText);
        addNumberBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //etPhoneNumber.add(new EditText(ContactEdit.this));
                try{
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacteditll);

                    EditText temp = new EditText(ContactEdit.this);
                    temp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                

                    etPhoneNumber.add(temp);

                    layout.addView(temp);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create new edit text");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:baselineAligned="true" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/contacteditll"
  android:background="@drawable/darkimg">

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titlePrint"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titlePrompt"
        />

      <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spContactTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/titlePrompt"
        />

    <TextView 
     android:text="@string/namePrint"
     android:id="@+id/namePrint" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </TextView>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:hint="@string/returnName" 
    android:id="@+id/etFirstNameInput" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf= "@+id/namePrint">
    </EditText>

     <TextView 
     android:text="@string/secondPrint"
     android:id="@+id/secondPrint" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </TextView>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:hint="@string/returnName" 
    android:id="@+id/etSecondNameInput" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf= "@+id/namePrint">
    </EditText>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/numberPrint"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/numberPrint">
    </TextView>

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumberInput" 
    android:hint="@string/returnNumber">
    </EditText>

    <Button android:id="@+id/addNumberEditText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:text="ADD"
    />


     <include 
     android:id="@+id/customedittext"
     layout="@layout/myedittext"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/emailPrint" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/emailPrint">
    </TextView>

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/etEmailAddressInput" 
    android:hint="@string/returnEmail">
    </EditText>

    <Button 
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/btnSaveButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailInput" 
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever I click on my button the action is heard but nothing is done. The layout of the page does not change even though the new edit text is in my list of edit texts and I am adding the new edit text to the layout.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is the orientation of contacteditll? If you add the button from xml is it working right ?

Comment: The button is in the xml. The orientation is vertical.

Comment: I added the xml. What I am trying to do is if the user clicks the button, create a new edit text to allow them to enter another number.

Comment: I suppose contacteditll is the outer layout that holds all views. It works fine with me. The edittext is added in the bottom of the layout. What is the height of customedittext. I think the problem here is that the edittext is added but it's outside the screen, add scroll.

Comment: [Check also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438475/unable-to-dynamically-add-edittext-to-linearlayout/19682246#19682246)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure gets added but you are not seeing it cause there is no space left. Two things to test:

- Place the `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.
- Use the weight parameter.

Using the weight parameter:

```
EditText temp = new EditText(ContactEdit.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
temp.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Things are possibly offscreen. I tried the weighting but that didn't seem to work. So to put in a scroll view do I enclose the Linear Layout tag in the ScrollView tag?

Comment: My screen just goes black when I enclose the linear layout in scroll view. I'm sorry to keep asking you questions.

Comment: Wait I got it thanks for the help. Now I have to put the edit text in the right place. Thanks

Comment: would be nice to share after you find something out for other. I was looking for the same thing right now :'(