# Unable to dynamically add EditText to LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have read many post similar to this, but none of them resolved my problem. Another funny thing is, on the emulator the place for the edittext is held (meaning other widgets are shifted down), but is not shown, on the other hand the same implementation on the real phone doesn't even show a place for the widget. I have the following `LinearLayout` inside which I need to dynamically add an `EditText` widget when the `TextView` **Add a Team Member** is clicked.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_add_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/yellow_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_task_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_check_research_tasks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_check_empty" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_task_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:text="Task Name"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_add_team_member"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Add a team member"
                android:textColor="@color/text_green"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_add_task"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_add_team_member"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_create_assignment_attach"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_flag_alt" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Due"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="65"
                    android:hint="None"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_calendar_empty" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_create_assignment_trash"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Trash" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_create_assignment_done"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Done" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java code, the `onClickListener` implementation of the TextView.

```
tvAddTeamMember.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_task_name);
            EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            et.setLayoutParams(p);
            et.setText("Text");
            ll.addView(et);

        }
```

Comment: Try to set Gravity for Edittext..

Comment: @PiyushGupta Setting the gravity didn't do.

Comment: You have orientation horizontal, and you are putting `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` property for your edit view. This is some what not acceptable.

Comment: @Tarsem So what is the best practice?

Comment: @ChintanRathod yeah you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @Anas Azeem: your code is correct.through your code we can add editetxt  to linear layout dynamically. problem is in the layout file only.in the layout mentioned the orientation for added layout as "horizontal" ,instead of that one use "vertical" like below

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_task_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_check_research_tasks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_task_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:text="Task Name"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may proceed this way ! This is not what you're looking for. But your problem will get resolved.

1) By default add the EditText view in your XML and make it invisible.

2) On Clicking the TextView, make it visible.

enjoy !

Comment: The number of Editexts to be added is not limited.

Comment: do you need to create n number of edittext views under n number of textviews or the edittext views can be used as vertical listing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the line :

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

**With this:**

```
  android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams p= new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 //Then do your work
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you might be adding a layout, you could always declare ViewStub. After that you simply find the viewStub and call inflate() on it:

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

This is the promoted way to do that in Android SDK. Thanks to that you can define the infalte layout in an xml file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not have definite number of Edittext to be added they may be many of them. So, how can your answer be used in my scenario?

Comment: When there are many possible EditTexts to be added, it cannot be used.

Comment: you may declare a counter variable that counts the number of edittext views, on each click give it a +1 value.Then, you may use the counter variable to get the number of edittext views.in case there might be some data in edittextes, then you can store the same in an ArrayList<String> and use the same. I hope it will work !

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.
replace ur line      ll.addView(et);

by::
ll.addView(et,p);

and delete ur line et.setLayoutParams(p);

Comment: Sorry, the issue is as it was.

Comment: change ur et_task_name edittext width to be wrap_content in ur layout file.and then try to run ur code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this.

```
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_checkpoint);
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addLayout);        
        // layout has assigned weight = "1.0" in xml & it's a child of ScrollView
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater oLayoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                // oView is declared globally & Layout "row_checkpoint" contains a EditText
                oView = oLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checkpoint, null);

                final EditText speciesEditText = (EditText) oView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkpoint); 
                speciesEditText.setId(layout.getChildCount());
                // Perform whatever required over EditText, same way you can add more elements.
                layout.addView(oView);
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help.