# How to get all text from dynamically added edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to android. Now i am need to know how to get text values of all edittext which has added dynamically when user press add button.

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
row = new TableRow(Material.this);
table.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 edit = new EditText(Material.this); 
 edit.setWidth(135);
 edit.setHeight(35);
 edit.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
 row.addView(edit); 
table.addView(row);
```

Here how to get text values of edittext? User may add more than one edittext. At that case, how to get all text?

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: plz show what have u tried so far

Comment: you must try at-least something

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically add edit text to a layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493817/dynamically-add-edit-text-to-a-layout)

Comment: no body's gonna write your code for you.You must search on net and try something.If any problem comes then people are gonna help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditTexts` are created dynamically with a reference use that reference to get the value of it.

**For Example**

I have created an `editText`.

```
EditText myTextBox = new EditText(getBaseContext());
containerLayout.addView(myTextBox);
```

Here, `myTextBox` would be the variable which refers to that `editText`, you could use `getText()` to get the value of that box or you could use `setText()` to set the value to that box.

```
String value = myTextBox.getText().toString();
myTextBox.setText("this is the setted text");`
```

**EDIT**

If there are more than one `editText` then add all the references in an array and iterate over them.

```
List<EditText> myArray = new ArrayList();
EditText editText1 = new EditText(getBaseContext());
 containerLayout.addView(editText1);
 myArray.add(editText1);

EditText editText2 = new EditText(getBaseContext());
 containerLayout.addView(editText2);
 myArray.add(editText2);

EditText editText3 = new EditText(getBaseContext());
 containerLayout.addView(editText3);
 myArray.add(editText3);
 int i = 0;
    while (i < myArray.size()) {
        Log.i(TAG,myArray.get(i).getText());
        i++;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: ok nice. if user add more than one edittext mean? how to get all edittext values?

Comment: i cant able to declare List

Comment: `List<EditText> myArray = new ArrayList();` This worked for me.

Comment: this is error.pls solve                                                                                          - Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to 
  List<EditText>
 - List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized
 - Cannot instantiate the type List

Comment: oh. are you using arraylist? see ur code above. you r using list itself

Comment: that won't be a problem :)

Comment: yes that was prob to me. now solved. but i couldn't get output.

Comment: it says nothing. but no error. wait i will try  with ur image. are u from india?. i hope so.

Comment: hello, thanks... error has fixed. ur image ahs helped me a lot

Comment: Upvote and accept if you feel I helped you and think it might help others

Comment: yes. its too fixed. thanks for ur help... keep helping to needy. hatsoff

Comment: I suggest you to post another question for that.

Answer (score 2):

If `EditText`s are dynamically added maintain the references of `EditText` in an array and when ever you want text from them iterate the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created edit text and text is set in edit text then:

```
String text = edittext.getText().toString();
```

would be okay.

Comment: it must must not work for dynamically added edittext.

Comment: can you write some code here so that I can check how you are creating the edit text and what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep reference of that dynamically added EditText.

And call getText().toString(); on that reference.

One other approach is to set some ids using setId(); keep record of those ids and whenever required.

```
((EditText)findViewById(edittextidyouset)).getText().toString();
```

Take look at this thread setting ids dynamically : [How can I assign an ID to a view programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you-

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editTexts.add(editText);
            editText.setText("I am at " + i);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
        }
        for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
            Log.d("Texts", editText.getText().toString());
        }
```

Your xml file can be like-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.hestabit.activity.Home">


</LinearLayout>
```